# Nth child but linked to first child

Tags: html, css

I wrote the nth child css line to hide the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th span tags inside of the li element.  When I run this it does it for all three unordered lists, I only want it to do this to the first one. How can I fix the code so it hides the second, third, and fourth span tags inside li element of only the first unordered list?

```css
li.sample span:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none !important:
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="sample">
    <span class="1">test</span>
    <span class="2">test</span>
    <span class="3">test</span>
    <span class="4">test</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="sample">
    <span class="1">test</span>
    <span class="2">test</span>
    <span class="3">test</span>
    <span class="4">test</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="sample">
    <span class="1">test</span>
    <span class="2">test</span>
    <span class="3">test</span>
    <span class="4">test</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add an id to that first list and then apply the css to that id.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add a second class to your first "sample" div, for example "sample-first" and select it through that. If you need to leave your markup as it is, you can select the first sample by `ul:first-of-type li.sample span:nth-child(n+2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well there could be several options, although in my opinion if you will always have 4 elements, the easiest would be to use the `~` selector. That would actually apply even if you have more than 4 elements to all the following elements. Below is a code example where I commented the `display: none` definition, so that you can see how the elements are affected.

```css
ul.sampleul:first-of-type>li.sample span:first-child~span {
  color: red;
  /* display: none; */
}
```

```html
<ul class="sampleul">
  <li class="sample">
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sampleul">
  <li class="sample">
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sampleul">
  <li class="sample">
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also, you can't use class names with numbers only.

Comment: I like what you have setup! I need to make it so that it only applies to the first UL and the other two stay normal.

Comment: @BrandonWelch I updated my answer to what I think you are trying to achieve. Just in case I recommend adding a class to the `ul` elements you want to affect, because if you use only `ul:first-of-type` it would literally select the first `ul` element in the page.

Comment: Did it do the trick @BrandonWelch ?